# Parent tag has no default property warning in FXML file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

I am trying to place several [`<fx:define>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#define_elements) with `<ArrayList>` inside a FXML file

[image]

IntelliJ accepts some of them but warns about others. Why?

Comment: Seems like a bug in the IDE. I also noticed this problem. According to http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.java#145 this should work as expected and not be an error.